# Docker : Permissions on a directory not copied when files are copied to volumes

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Here is the relevant part of my Dockerfile :

```
RUN cd /path/to/future/volume \
 && if [ ! -d "init_data" ]; then tar xvzf init_data.tar.gz; fi \
 && chmod 775 init_data
```

In my docker-compose, I'm using a named volume mapped on /path/to/future/volume (my-volume:/path/to/future/volume), so Docker is supposed to copy all files from /path/to/future/volume to my host directory.

The copy itself works (and all users and groups ownership seem good) EXCEPT my chmod 775 init_data is not applied.

If after the volume creation, I go into the container and lauch "chmod 775 init_data" it works inside the container and in the volume, but I need to set this write permission on group at build time.

Why is this happening and what could I do as a workaround ?

Comment: Did you add the chmod to your Dockerfile after the volume was first created?

Comment: Ok, I tried to remove the volume before "docker-compose up -d" and the correct rights were applied to init_data inside the volume, so it's all good. I'm not sure about the exact copy/overwrite/merge rules when you run a container using existing named volumes (maybe no copy at all when the volume already exists ?).

Comment: That's just about correct, no volume after the volume exists with data inside. If the volume is completely empty, I believe it also initializes, but certainly if the volume doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker only initializes named volumes when they are empty. Once they have data inside, the initialization step is skipped (otherwise it would risk overwriting or deleting your data).

So to see changes introduced from your new image, you need to remove not only your old container, but also your old volume.

Note that this doesn't apply to host volumes (binding a path directly from the docker host into the container). Even when empty, host volumes are never initialized.